# Which technique is used to update the values inside the combo box dynamically?

Tags: java, javascript, c++, html, combobox

I'm making a webpage and in it the values inside the combo box depends upon the selection of some other field like for registration form by selecting a specific country, the combo box for the states displays the states of only that country. So does this dynamic allocation of values to the combo box occurs with javascript or with some back-end programming language like java or C++? If it can occur through both than which would be more advisable to use?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello Saumil Soni, Welcome to Stack Overflow. First I would like to inform you that the Back-End Programming language in web-development are not usually java or C++ but its ASP, JSP, PHP,etc. Read about the server side scripting languages and have a grip in any one of them (I personally suggest PHP as a beginner) because you need them for what you intend to do. [Your selection of tags java, C++, html, javascript and combobox in a single question just raised my heart-beats ]

Comment: @sumitb.mdi `JSP` is short for "Java Server Pages". Java is actually quite popular among web-developers, there are frameworks such as `Spring-MVC` specifically for web-development.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg I completely agree about your thought on JSP (I myself am a JSP developer) But I meant that JAVA (as a programming language) is not used in its original form on back-end.

Comment: @sumitb.mdi When it comes to C++, many embedded devices don't have the OOMPH to run heavier systems, so we have to make do with C++ web servers / dynamic content generation (granted, it's kind of a niche, but it's still a reality). ;)

Comment: @sumitb.mdi yep sorry man I'm still about to get used to the tags here. Yeah PHP would be good but I really want to go with Java(JSP) here.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* technically set the values of the `select`'s `options` (I am assuming that is what you mean by a `combo` box) by doing multiple roundtrips to the backend, remembering all submitted values and then rendering HTML which has the correct options selected back to the user.

**However, that is what used to happen 10 years ago.**

Now, using Javascript for this task is a nobrainer. There are two ways of doing this using Javascript too, depending on how complex the logic for deciding what options to populate the `select` boxes is. If it requires several DB queries, then it is best to perform an `ajax` call to the backend request for the options while temporarily suspending the UI and showing a loading screen.

If the decision is simple, then you should do it on the client, using only Javascript and without performing calls to the backend. This last options is the preferred one since it keeps the UI responsive and does not cause any extra load on the backend.

Comment: Just remember, when you design this kind of things, that you should always be able to fall back on a solution without JavaScript (ie. with back-end calls). Estimates are that about 10% of visitors explicitly disable JS in their browsers to avoid security problems.

Comment: Wow, 10% sounds like a really large fraction. This is interesting, could you please give me a source for that information? I would like to find out more.

Comment: @musically_ut I don't have a source at hand, but that's roughly the numbers I remember. Maybe 9% would be closer, I remember thinking "*wow that's nearly 1 in 10*". Still, that's huge compared to what I was expecting.